# Sybase stored procedure exception handling

Tags: exception, stored-procedures, error-handling, sybase

I am new to sybase. After studying a bit I came to know following is the correct way to handle error/exceptions in sybase stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_testErrorHandling (@age varchar(20))
AS
BEGIN
 DECLARE @myerr int

    BEGIN TRANSACTION mytrans

    DELETE FROM TestStoredProc where Name='Z'
    IF @@error<>0 BEGIN SELECT @myerr=@@error GOTO failed END

    DECLARE @result int
    EXECUTE @result = 5/0  /* throws an exception */
    IF @@error<>0 BEGIN SELECT @myerr=@@error GOTO failed END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION mytrans
    RETURN 0

    failed:
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION mytrans
    return @myerr

END
```

I thought, this stored procedure would return the error code correspondin to exception devision by zero. But actually it is throwing exception. Please help me to undestand the behaviour.
Regards,
Anirban
Anirban

Answer (score 1):

To be able to capture / handle 'divide by zero' errors better, you will have to set appropriate values to the **arithignore arith_overflow**  system option in the Sybase server.  There is some good documentation in the Sybase online manual at :

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1550/html/sqlug/X47118.htm

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you assign `@@error` to any variable, then value of `@@error` becomes `0`.
To avoid this user temp table & insert @@error into that temp table then again fetch value from table and use that value.

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_testErrorHandling (@age varchar(20))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @myerr int
CREATE TABLE #errorCode (errorCode INT)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION mytrans

DELETE FROM TestStoredProc where Name='Z'
INSERT INTO #errorCode values(@@error)
SELECT @myerr = errorCode FROM  #errorCode
IF @myerr<>0 BEGIN  GOTO failed END

DECLARE @result int
EXECUTE @result = 5/0  /* throws an exception */
INSERT INTO #errorCode values(@@error)
SELECT @myerr = errorCode FROM  #errorCode
IF @myerr<>0 BEGIN GOTO failed END

COMMIT TRANSACTION mytrans
RETURN 0

failed:
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION mytrans
return @myerr
```

END